# Django - When [and why] use Vue.js?

Tags: jquery, django, vue.js

I've developed with my team a large application that uses the classic django MVT lifecycle.
The templates, are implemented with the classic Bootstrap + JQuery stack, using AJAX requests and so on...

Everything works fine and it's quite easy to maintain.

Today, i've had a briefing with my collegue, he saw the web-application templates and he told that: "Using the classic Django Template it's discouraged and it represent a big effort to maintain in some big projects..."

Additionally, he gave me the advice to use Vue.JS for the templating...i've seen some examples and tutorial about Vue.JS...i've found that this templating framework it's quite complex and unuseful for my use case (The most complex templates builds a bunch of graphs and widgets)

In conclusion, i'm a bit confused when and why a Django project needs to be scaled using a template framework or not.

I suppose (...maybe wrong...) that this templating frameworks represents a temporary fashion way to achieve the same results...

What is your idea on top of these considerations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the only question you have to wonder first is, did your project need SEO, if yes :

- I wouldn't recommend using react.js or vue.js cause it not as easy as simple HTML for SEO.

If not :

- Then, you can choose react or vue, for better more dynamic FrontEnd.

But if no one in your team knows react/vue like a boss stay on a simple template.

And you can first create conventions /  tests / styleguide for your frontend.

Answer (score 2):

its better have backend and frontend, separete, you can use templates when its for a basic proyect, if not is the case, you should use Django Rest Framework for create API's and other framework for Frontend like: Vue.js. React JS etc .

Answer (score 1):

I completely agree with you... I was on a big project where we started adding all of that front end back end separation, just to have a even buggier mess because of the lack of experience and the requirement of new people with those set of tools...

Django comes with many securities built in than are lost after you go for the api/front end route. For me, having a website with Django, jQuery and Bootstrap was the way to go. But Vue and Axios with their CDN, is a great way change the website if you are looking for fancier stuff.

And for the app, http response and the Django serializers are enough for not having to go to the rest framework.